# How do I jump to the next line with the same indent level?

Tags: search, indentation, navigation

I have a space formatted (yaml) file like the following:

```
en:
  templates:
    template: "VERYLONGTEXTHEREWITHHUNDREDSOFLINES"
  destination: "I want to jump here"
    other: stuff
  further_destination:
    foo: bar
  yet_more_destinations:
    foo: bar
```

Is there any easy command to walk through from the beginning of `templates:` to `destination:` and ideally be able to continue on to `further_destination:` and `yet_more_destinations:`?

Comment: I highly recommend EasyMotion, https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that some plugins might do what you want: they create text objects based on the indentation and then let you navigate between these text objects.

But installing a plugin just for that is not always the best solution: you could do it by youself with a bit of vimscript to add to your `vimrc`:

First let's create a function which loops on the lines of the buffer and goes to the first line with the same indentation level:

```
function! GoToNextIndent(inc)
    " Get the cursor current position
    let currentPos = getpos('.')
    let currentLine = currentPos[1]
    let matchIndent = 0

    " Look for a line with the same indent level whithout going out of the buffer
    while !matchIndent && currentLine != line('$') + 1 && currentLine != -1
        let currentLine += a:inc
        let matchIndent = indent(currentLine) == indent('.')
    endwhile

    " If a line is found go to this line
    if (matchIndent)
        let currentPos[1] = currentLine
        call setpos('.', currentPos)
    endif
endfunction
```

Note that the argument `inc` should be `1` or `-1` depending on the way (down or up) you want to scan the buffer.

Then you can simply call the function `:call GoToNextIndent(1)` or create two convenient mappings:

```
nnoremap ni :call GoToNextIndent(1)<CR>
nnoremap pi :call GoToNextIndent(-1)<CR>
```

Here `ni` in normal mode will go to the next line with the same indent level and `pi` to the previous line.

*You might want to change the mapped keys to something which doesn't mess with your configuration*

Comment: Cool, thanks for the code!

This is actually the first time I've run into something I thought vim could do natively and it actually can't, and is not just me not knowing how.

Answer (score 4):

If your indenting is consistent, as shown above, you can use:

```
/^  [^ ]
```

`/`: search for the next occurrence of

`^`  : the start of a line, followed by two spaces

`[^ ]`: followed by any character that's not a space

Since your file is space-formatted, this is sufficient to correctly jump to each of the tags you mentioned. This command will jump you to the first occurrence it finds, and then you can hit `n` repeatedly to scan through all other occurrences.